# Pixelation caused when shrinking image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am getting 8 4K videos and shrinking them using cv2.resize(...). But there is some pixelation that occurs
Here is my code:

```
NUM=8

blank=np.zeros((1080//NUM,1920//NUM,3), np.uint8)
cv2.namedWindow("win",cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)
i=0
t=datetime.now()
while key!=ord("q"):
    check_fill_caps(caps,vids)
    frames=[]
    for c in caps:
        ret,frame=c.read()
        if ret:
           frame=cv2.resize(frame,(1920//NUM,1080//NUM),interpolation=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        else:
           frame=blank
        frames.append(frame)
    if len(frames)%2 !=0:
        frames.append(blank)
    
    up=np.concatenate(tuple(frames[0:len(frames)//2]),axis=1)
    down=np.concatenate(tuple(frames[len(frames)//2:]),axis=1)
    whole=np.concatenate((up,down),axis=0)
    cv2.imshow("win",whole)
    key=cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I tried interpolation cv2.INTER_LINEAR

Comment: If I do not resize it, Then no pixelation occurs when opencv automatically rsizes for displaying in imshow window

Comment: Are you talking about the actual resized image or the image displayed on OpenCV's window via imshow? As far as I recall, imshow does not use any interpolation while resizing the image embedded in the window.

Comment: I am talking about image displayed by opencv's window(cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL allows smaller windows than actual image size)